# Docker limit the size of a volume

Tags: php, apache, docker

I make a simple Apache/PHP5 docker environment who use tutum/apache-php.

My docker-compose.yml dile :

```
web:
 build: apache
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 volumes:
  - /var/www/html/erp:/var/www
  - /var/www/html/erp/conf/php/php.ini:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/30-custom.ini
  - /var/www/html/erp/conf/apache/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

My Apache Dockerfile :

```
FROM  tutum/apache-php
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -yq install php5-mcrypt && apt-get -yq install php5-mcrypt
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

I had a problem with the volume size of my /var/www volumetutum/apache.

When I make this command : df -h

```
/dev/dm-0           15G     15G     0 100% /
udev                10M       0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs              397M    396K  397M   1% /run
tmpfs              5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              794M       0  794M   0% /run/shm
```

/dev/sda1          228M     49M  167M  23% /boot
tmpfs              935M     16K  935M   1% /tmp
cgroup             2,0G       0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup`

I can see that my volume is full (15G) but I need 19G to put all my project.

What can I do?

Comment: https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_limiting_disk_space

Comment: Thanks, but, is there a way to do this with docker compose ?

Comment: As a side comment I think that `RUN /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` is useless.

Comment: What is your OS? Is it windows or MacOS? If you use docker though boot2docker, you would  have to increase the disk size of the VM right?

Comment: I'm using a debian7 x64 VM who work on Vmware. I have a disk with 85Go.

Comment: What is the output of `df -h` from your host (the VM)? (Just to be sure).

Comment: And also the comment from @stdob-- looks pertinent. Can you try to restart the docker daemon with let's say `--storage-opt dm.basesize=30G` I think this can be tuned in `/etc/default/docker` on debian (not sure though).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I have some problems with my Vmware VM.

Comment: That is partitioning problem. problem solved !